# Why does this loop cause a Key error if the second embedded "if" statement is commented out?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement, quantitative-finance

I have a dataframe of stock data called stocks that looks like this:

```
stocks.head()

                     RET    MktRet  Mkt-RF  ...      RF   XMktRet      XRET
permno date                                 ...                            
10001  2007-01  0.023279  0.019397  0.0140  ...  0.0044  0.014997  0.018879
       2007-02  0.261621 -0.013988 -0.0196  ...  0.0038 -0.017788  0.257821
       2007-03  0.019732  0.012950  0.0068  ...  0.0043  0.008650  0.015432
       2007-04  0.002764  0.039815  0.0349  ...  0.0044  0.035415 -0.001636
       2007-05  0.043418  0.038932  0.0324  ...  0.0041  0.034832  0.039318

[5 rows x 8 columns]

    stocks.tail()

Out[3]: 
                     RET    MktRet  Mkt-RF  ...      RF   XMktRet      XRET
permno date                                 ...                            
93436  2018-08  0.011806  0.030221  0.0344  ...  0.0016  0.028621  0.010206
       2018-09 -0.122290  0.000443  0.0006  ...  0.0015 -0.001057 -0.123790
       2018-10  0.274011 -0.074031 -0.0768  ...  0.0019 -0.075931  0.272111
       2018-11  0.039013  0.018530  0.0169  ...  0.0018  0.016730  0.037213
       2018-12 -0.050445 -0.089810 -0.0955  ...  0.0019 -0.091710 -0.052345

[5 rows x 8 columns]
```

I'm attempting to iterate through each "permno" (company) to run a regression on each subset and return the results into a new dataframe called "stats". I originally wanted to filter out indexes for which there were fewer than 60 observations and came up with this working code:

```
# estimate CAPM betas and t-statistics for all firms with more than 60 months of data
stats = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan, index=stocks.index.get_level_values(0).unique(),
                     columns=['beta', 't-stat', 'White t-stat'])
ct=0 # initialize counter
for permno in stats.index:
    ct+=1 # advance counter
    if np.mod(ct, 500)==0:
        print("On stock", ct, "at", strtimenow())
    # must have 60 obs
    if (stocks.loc[permno].dropna().shape[0]) < 60:
        continue
    
    reg = sm.OLS(endog=stocks.loc[permno]['XRET'], 
                 exog=sm.add_constant(stocks.loc[permno]['XMktRet']),
                 missing='drop').fit()
    stats.loc[permno] = (
        reg.params['XMktRet'], 
        reg.tvalues['XMktRet'],
        (reg.params/reg.HC0_se)['XMktRet']
        )
```

If I wanted to remove this restriction, and therefore comment out the second "if" statement, I get a Key error. Why is this? I've tried adding "continue" after the first if statement but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: What's the error exactly? The `continue` will cause the bottom half of the loop to be skipped, so if any code there causes an error, the error won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

to comment something you have to add # to every line of  code you want to be this way so there the code isn´t on comment format at all. Or if you want to follow the logic you just did you might write pass instead of continue :) I hope that my answer helped in a way, if you think it´s worth remember to give me the points so i can continue contributing to this amazing community.

Comment: The code I pasted in is the working version, but when I do put a # on each line of the second "if" statement, that's when I get the error. Why does the code break if I simply delete those lines?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest commenting this out as well, to begin with:

```
reg = sm.OLS(endog=stocks.loc[permno]['XRET'], 
                 exog=sm.add_constant(stocks.loc[permno]['XMktRet']),
                 missing='drop').fit()
    stats.loc[permno] = (
        reg.params['XMktRet'], 
        reg.tvalues['XMktRet'],
        (reg.params/reg.HC0_se)['XMktRet']
        )
```

Then back in one statement at a time.  This way you can figure out just where you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Would be great to check at which line it returns this error. I would guess that *reg* object is different when stock has less than 60 observations, hence it returns error in `stats.loc[permno]` line, or stats is missing *permno* itself.

If *stocks* is dataframe I would bet it has *'XRET'* or *'XMktRet'* key, (you showed it anyway).

```
 reg = sm.OLS(endog=stocks.loc[permno]['XRET'], 
                 exog=sm.add_constant(stocks.loc[permno]['XMktRet']),
                 missing='drop').fit()
 
stats.loc[permno] = (
     reg.params['XMktRet'], 
     reg.tvalues['XMktRet'],
     (reg.params/reg.HC0_se)['XMktRet']
     )
```

When code is running in a loop and encounters *Continue*, loop stops there and takes next item.

Commenting more lines won't help you, better add *print* lines where you can really see how object looks, or use builtin debugger mode, (or anything similar in your IDE if you are using one).